# Bootstrap 3 right align button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to right align a button in a grid:

[image]

I would like the button on the right to align with the text area above it.

My code looks something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        Purchase Order
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <textarea />
        <textarea />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <button />
                <button />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <button />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried adding offsets and adjusting the spans of the different columns...the button is either too far to the left or the right. I have tried adding a fixed margin-left to the right button, this works but it breaks the responsive design.

---

#### NOTE:

I can't use pull-right, it is deprecated in Bootstrap 3.

Comment: It's not deprecated in bootstrap 3. If you don't have it, just create a class called .pull-right with a rule that says "float: right !important;"

Comment: Regardless, using the float doesn't fix the problem. The button is either too far are to the left or the right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here it is with inline styles. You could also create your own `.pull-right` class.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        Purchase Order
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
        <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
        <button style="float: right">Button Right</button>
        <button>Button One</button>
        <button>Button Two</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Optional CSS**

```
.pull-right {
    float: right !important; // Use of important emulates bootstrap
}
```

Comment: Not that this is incorrect, but inline styling is generally bad practice. Particularly when using a framework, such as Bootstrap. Still not sure why OP doesn't have access to `pull-right` though.

Answer (score 25):

Normally Bootstrap has its own class to pull elements to the right. Try this:

```
<button class="pull-right">Hello</button>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can give `text-left` and `text-right` a try. They are built in Bootstrap 3 classes that do not require floating divs.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/17068/)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        Purchase Order
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 text-left">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save PO Tages & Notes</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Add PO Notes to Calendar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

NOTE - I changed your HTML up a bit to make the fiddle look better. They obviously aren't required.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i found this solution

```
<div style="float: right; margin-top: 30px;" class="col-12">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Entrar</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <button />
        <button />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <button />
    </div>
</div>
```

...you have col-xs-9 and col-cs-2 whitch dont add to 12 columns bootstrap grid system. Mayby **changing col-xs-9** to **col-xs-10** will solve your problem? Or this and pull-right class.

Comment: No, as I said in the OP, changing the cols doesn't fix it. You don't need all of the cols to layout a grid, anyway.